# How to sum those cells in Excel with specific color?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

I didn't find any command in Excel to work with fore color of cell items or back color. How can I use a Sum or SumIf statement in Excel 2013 to sum only those cells that are not good (black ones excluding green ones)?

Comment: If you are using conditional formatting to set the color, can you use the criteria here?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008632/excel-can-i-create-a-conditional-formula-based-on-the-color-of-a-cell